# Bing Maps AJAX Control v7 Directions module fails randomly

Tags: bing-maps

I have implemented the [Bing Maps AJAX Control v7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx) in a website that has 4 predefined walking routes that the user can choose. The chosen route will then be displayed on the map via the Directions module (`directionsManager.calculateDirections()`) and also the textual description will show up in a `div` container next to the map.

It all works fine, except that ***sometimes*** the directions are not returned by the API and I get the following error returned in the [error callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh312837.aspx):

```
Object { 
  responseCode: 17, 
  message: "Fußwege sind derzeit nicht verfügba…", // This is german for: "walking directions are currently not available"
  eventName: "directionsError" 
}
```

The routes are given in a JSON as simple array of waypoints. Because it does work ***sometimes***, I would conclude the problem does have nothing to do with the waypoints itself.

Note that it does not matter whether the directions are fetched for walking or driving (same error code).

**So my questions are:**

1. Do I just have to live with it? If so, what would be best practice to handle the situation regarding user experience?
2. If not, what could be the cause for this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your account is being rate limited. This occurs to trial and basic Bing Maps keys when either your account is consuming transactions at a rate that will exceed the free terms of use, or when the service is under a lot of load from others who are using Bing Maps under the free terms of use. The only way to limit the possibility of being rate limited is to upgrade to an Enterprise key. If you are using an enterprise key and are seeing this issue, then contact the Bing Maps Enterprise support team and they will investigate.

Comment: You are right, we are using the "basic" Bing Maps API key. I did not read anything about the limitations, but what you say sounds reasonable to me... Guess we have to consider switching to the enterprise key. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: There is some documentation on this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701703.aspx I believe it is also documented in the terms of use somewhere.